# How are items in a list correlated to a variable even when there is no specific variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new and currently learning python and I don't understand how the game images are connected and is showing the correlated image to the choices rock, paper, and scissors even when there is no specific variable assigned to it. I am sorry for my lack of knowledge and I hope someone clarifies and explains this supposedly easy knowledge well to me! Thank you.

```
import random

rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''
game_images = [rock, paper, scissors]

user_choice = int(input("What do you choose? Type 0 for Rock, 1 for Paper or 2 for Scissors.\n"))
if user_choice >= 3 or user_choice < 0: 
    print("You typed an invalid number, you lose!") 
else:
    print(game_images[user_choice])

    computer_choice = random.randint(0, 2)
    print("Computer chose:")
    print(game_images[computer_choice])


    if user_choice == 0 and computer_choice == 2:
        print("You win!")
    elif computer_choice == 0 and user_choice == 2:
        print("You lose")
    elif computer_choice > user_choice:
        print("You lose")
    elif user_choice > computer_choice:
        print("You win!")
    elif computer_choice == user_choice:
        print("It's a draw")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping is made with the list object created as:

```
game_images = [rock, paper, scissors]
```

The list elements `rock`, `paper` and `scissors` map to the string objects defined above.

So, when the user enters a value between `0` and `2`, the respectively value from the list is then selected with `game_images[user_choice]` and printed as:

```
print(game_images[user_choice])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access game-image list using built-in range function.

```
game_images = [rock, paper, scissors]
for idx in range(len(game_images)):
    print(game_images[idx])
```